# Firebase not rendering Angular Components

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

I connected to firebase, but I can't get it to render my Angular tags.  I've followed the below article and several others, and I'm just not getting it to render.

[Angular 4 Firebase - HTML not rendering / reading angular tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395573/angular-4-firebase-html-not-rendering-reading-angular-tag)

When I deploy to firebase, it renders "test 3" from the native HTML, but not the app-root or component1.
It's driving me crazy!  Can someone help?

Index from dist folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting </title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-remote-config.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-performance.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    test 3
    <app-root></app-root>
    <app-component1></app-component1>
  </body>
```

environment (and environment.prod):

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "test1-9b8fb.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "test1-9b8fb",
    storageBucket: "test1-9b8fb.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "..."
  }
};
```

.firebasesrc:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "test1-9b8fb"
  },
  "targets": {
    "test1-9b8fb": {
      "hosting": {
        "firebase-test": [
          "test1-9b8fb"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "firebase-test": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/firebase-test",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/app",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "firebase-test:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "firebase-test:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "firebase-test:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "firebase-test:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "firebase-test:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "firebase-test"
}
```

app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Component1Component } from './component1/component1.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Component1Component,
   
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-component1></app-component1>
App works!
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

component1.component.html:

```
<p>component1 works!</p>
```

[Angular 4 Firebase - HTML not rendering / reading angular tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395573/angular-4-firebase-html-not-rendering-reading-angular-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.  Everywhere that talks about this subject says to use "dist" for your public file, but that's not quite right.  I set it to "dist/firebase-test" and it worked just fine.

Turns out the index.html in "dist" doesn't automatically go one level down to get to the app component stuff.